# Error while installing rails json gem - bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm having problems with the Rails installation on Windows. It cannot install the json gem, with the error message below.

```
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...........
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0

Gem::InstallError: The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: You are not supposed to upload on a third party side. Stackoverflow provides a way to upload an image and attach it in your question for you.

Answer (score 9):

Run this command-

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

Comment: "... rails installation on **windows**"

Answer (score 5):

From reading the error screenshot, it seems as if your system is missing the necessary build tools required by some native C/C++ extensions.

You can try installing the RubyInstaller [Development Kit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/). This toolkit helps with using native C/C++ extensions for Ruby on your Windows machine.

Installation instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit).

After it's installed, run `gem update --system`, then try again.

Hope this helps!